# Adobe Access 3.0 DRM on Android

Tags: android, adobe, drm

As per the Adobe Access 3.0 spec , it seems that it can be supported on Android with flash player or Adobe Air App.

http://www.adobe.com/products/flashaccess/

did anybody has tried this ? looking for some feedback or reference on this.

What is the best/right way to integrate this with existing Android video application ?

1) WebView with flash swf file.

2) Starting the Adobe Air app from the Android app .

3) or I can integrate the adobe air into my existing android app.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your users would have to install Flash Player which is discontinued for Android and the installation would break the user journey of your app (they'll need to go to Play Store and install beforehand). I recommend to not take this route.

2) This might be possible, although I believe it will be quite difficult to get the Adobe Air app receiving some data from your main app, which I understand you will need? In any case other downsides will be: breaking the app in two pieces can cause confusion to user, accessing other state data from your main app, handling activity lifecycle for both apps.

3) This is not possible

Suggestion: 4) Wait for Adobe Access 4 native Android library to be released. I commented about it here:
[Android: Adobe Access DRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854963/android-adobe-access-drm/13471055#13471055)