# Android: Adobe Access DRM

Tags: android, air

We're developing a native `Android` streaming video player. And we want to implement `DRM` support in it. We've chosen `Adobe Access`. But we can't find any documentation about it for native app, only for `Adobe AIR` development.

So, here is the question: is there any way to use `Adobe Access` `DRM` in the native `Android` app?

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible soon. Adobe has been cooking a BETA of native Android libraries for Adobe Access. So far they haven't released/leaked anything yet. ETA could potentially be February, but my sources couldn't confirm this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The prevalence of rooted devices may make spending your development time making Adobe Access DRM work less helpful to your app customers than better device support, app testing, and feature development.

Likely you will have to invoke the Adobe Air app, and let it handle all the view/playback activity.

Adobe has a [quick start guide](http://www.adobe.com/support/adobeaccess/pdfs/server/AdobeAccess_4_QuickStart.pdf) (adobe.com PDF).